# How to add Respect Validation on child Object which is Optional

Tags: php, slim-3, respect-validation

In Slim3 framework's Respect Validation, I am trying to add validation on child object.

```
$childObjValidationArr = array(
  'param1' => v::regex("/^[A-Za-z0-9]{1}[A-Za-z0-9.$#-@]{1,19}$/"),
  'param2' => v::date('Y-m-d'),
  'param3' => v::intVal()->not(v::negative())
);
```

It works fine if child object is not optional.

```
$mainObjectValidators = array(
  'id' => $intPositive,
  'childObj' => $childObjValidationArr
);
```

But not working when child is optional (null allowed).

```
$mainObjectValidators = array(
  'id' => $intPositive,
  'childObj' => v::optional($childObjValidationArr)
);
```

Any way to add optional validation for child object with Respect?

Below is the error when attempted above

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Respect\Validation\Rules\Optional::__construct() must implement
>   interface Respect\Validation\Validatable, null given

Comment: You need to pass instance of `Respect\Validation\Validatable` interface when calling `Optional` constructor

Answer (score 0):

I have tried below

```
$childObjectValidator = v::when(v::notOptional(), 
v::attribute('pCode', $codeRegex)
->attribute('pDate', v::date('Y-m-d'))
->attribute('pId', $intPositiveZeroAllowed));
```

But then **KeySet** worked for me when combined it with **when**

```
$pValidator = v::keySet(
  v::key('pCode', $codeRegex),
  v::key('pDate, v::date('Y-m-d')),
  v::key('pId', $intPositiveZeroAllowed)
);

$childObjectValidator = v::when(v::notOptional(), $pValidator, v::nullType());
```

and main validator looks like below

```
$mainObjectValidators = array(
  'id' => $intPositive,
  'childObj' => $childObjectValidator
);
```